# Caching in python

Tags: python, class, oop, caching, global

I am trying to create a cache array that my function can modify and access multiple times.

I can achieve this using global variables:

```
def func():
    global cache
    cached_data = cache.get("some_key")
    if not cached_data:
        ...
    ...
```

I can also pass a parameter to the function:

```
def func(cache):
    cache.update({"stuff": 42})
    my_stuff = cache.get("stuff")

def main():
    func_cache = {}
    func(func_cache)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I can wrap this inside of a class:

```
class MyFunc:
    cache = {}
    @staticmethod
    def func():
        cached_data = cache.get("stuff")
    
def main():
    MyFunc.func()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I can do a lot of things, there are also tools like `@lru_cache`, but in this specific case I wanted to have control on what to save.
I asked this because maybe someone knew a good way to do this and uses it frequently, so it might help me and others with the same problem.

Comment: you should use oop

Comment: Please update your question with the `nonlocal` code you have tried.

Comment: [I answered a question a little while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75596519/8805293) where the user wanted to cache replacements of ID-values in their data structure. I solved it using classmethods that looked up already cached ID's before returning a newly generated ID. Are you looking for something like that?

Comment: @HampusLarsson at the time i wrote it my question was meant to be generic, which I understand is not a good thing.
However, I see that you used a similar approach as my last example, I thank you for your contibution.
If I remember correctly, at the time I asked this I was looking for a good way to cache elements within a single function. While it seems eccessive to use a class wrapper to do this kind of thing, if I need to do this kind of thing, I probably should use a class in the first place. Thank you for your contribution!