# Python replacing items

Tags: python, json

I would like to replace ID's which for now contain numbers and letters with unique ID which contains only numbers.

Id's now:

```
    "Id": "a4555752s"
    "SummaryId": "a4555752s"
    "Id": "a4asa85"
    "Id": "a4ddd244"
```

Second thing is that ID can be repeated in case if there are other items which belong to it and that would have to be changed together with specific ID if this is exact the same value like here.

```
"Id": "a4555752s"
"SummaryId": "a4555752s"
```

I wrote some code, but this is not very efficient since it is replacing all id's with one unique id.

Code:

```
    import json
    import random
    number = random.randint(1000,1000000)
    
    
    a = '''
{
  "people": [
    {
      "Name": "Jan",
      "Lastname": "Szewc",
      "Id": "174167"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Marek",
      "Lastname": "Piorun",
      "Id": "764120"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Mikolaj",
      "Lastname": "Ciekasz",
      "Id": "43409",
      "ManagerId": "a4555752s",
      "CoworkersId": [
        "1278978",
        "a4555752s"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
    '''
    data = json.loads(a)
    i = 0
    for item in (data["people"]):
        item["Id"] = item["Id"].replace(item["Id"], str(number))
    print(data["people"])
```

results:

```
[{'Name': 'Jan', 'Lastname': 'Szewc', 'Id': '853251'}, {'Name': 'Marek', 'Lastname': 'Piorun', 'Id': '853251'}, {'Name': 'Mikolaj', 'Lastname': 'Ciekasz', 'Id': '853251', 'SummaryId': 'a4555752s'}]
```

Can you give me some tips?

Comment: You want to put a random id instead of each actual id ?

Comment: I want to put some unique ID but this file has over 10k lines so I have decided to generate randomly maybe it is wrong approach.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to cache generated keys, so that if they are referred to later in the iterations, you can use the same `Id` to refer to another object.

There are built-in versions of caches, such as [`functools.cache`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/functools.html#functools.cache). However, this is how I would solve the problem without using that decorator:

```
import json
import random

class Cache:
    # A dictionary that keeps a record of "seen" keys
    key_cache = {}

    @classmethod
    def generate_replacement_key(cls, key: str) -> str:
        """
            If key has already been seen, then return the cached key for that, 
            otherwise generate and store a new key.
        """
        new_key = cls.key_cache.setdefault(key, cls.generate_random_key())
        return new_key
    
    @classmethod
    def generate_random_key(cls) -> str:
        """
            returns a random key, that hasn't been generated before
        """
        new_key = str(random.randint(1000, 1000000))
        if new_key in cls.key_cache.values():
            return cls.generate_random_key()
        return new_key

a = '''
{
  "people": [
    {
      "Name": "Jan",
      "Lastname": "Szewc",
      "Id": "a4555752s"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Marek",
      "Lastname": "Piorun",
      "Id": "a4asa85"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Mikolaj",
      "Lastname": "Ciekasz",
      "Id": "a4ddd244",
      "SummaryId": "a4555752s",
      "CoworkersId": [
        "1278978",
        "a4555752s"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
'''
data = json.loads(a)
for people in data["people"]:
    # use walrus operator to make less boilerplate-code.
    if (id_string := people.get("Id")): # use dict.get to avoid key-errors.
        people["Id"] = Cache.generate_replacement_key(id_string)
    if (summary_id_string := people.get("SummaryId")):
        people["SummaryId"] = Cache.generate_replacement_key(summary_id_string)
    # If the object contains a coworker_list, then we want to loop 
    # over each id in that list and replace them as well.
    if (coworkersId_list := people.get("CoworkersId")):
        for idx, coworker_id in enumerate(coworkersId_list):
            coworkersId_list[idx] = Cache.generate_replacement_key(coworker_id)

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

And a sample output:

```json
{
  "people": [
    {
      "Name": "Jan",
      "Lastname": "Szewc",
      "Id": "363988"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Marek",
      "Lastname": "Piorun",
      "Id": "381586"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Mikolaj",
      "Lastname": "Ciekasz",
      "Id": "736870",
      "SummaryId": "363988",
      "CoworkersId": [
        "888351",
        "363988"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: i think he want that SummaryId be same with id

Comment: @Stink If you look at his example JSON, then the `Id` of `Jan` is the same as `SummaryId` of `Mikolaj`, which is why I believe that he wants to cache the values. However, that is just an assumption, because the OP hasn't answered if that is the case or not.

Comment: yes  you right  lets see what he realy wants

Comment: @HampusLarsson Thank you for you help. I really appreciate this. This is what I wanted.  I wish you well :3

Comment: Hello, Hampus Larsson can you help me with this still? I need as well that code will change value Id, SummaryId and as well     "CoworkersId" the issue is that CoworkersId is a list. I have edited code in question. Maybe you know answer?

Comment: @LuiTe I've updated the answer to go over the list of Co-workers as well now. If you feel that this is a complete answer to your question, consider marking it as answered.

Comment: Thank you Hampus Larsson! I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

You need to use generate the random number in the loop, and don't use `str.replace` when replacing the whole value, just erase it

```
for item in data["people"]:
    item["Id"] = random.randint(1000, 1000000)
```

Comment: Yes it is works, though doesn't solve this issue with summaryID. It would have to work like "replace all" method. Any idea?

Comment: @azro This would also change the value type

Comment: I am not sure If I understand what do you mean cause Summary ID stays the same as it was. I would like it to be changed together with ID if the value is the same.  It has to be the same after change in this case it was "Id": "a4555752s"
"SummaryId": "a4555752s" after your code it will be "Id": f.e "425749" but SummaryID will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

in your case you havesometimes a key : SummaryId with this cod we can change both of them in that key exist and also you need this random number be a string right ?

```
for item in data["people"]:
    randonm_int = str(random.randint(1000, 1000000))
    item["Id"] = random_int
    try :
        item['SummaryId'] = random_int

    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Comment: it haven't changed SummaryId